# Can't figure out how to use Live Share on VS Mac 8.5.1

Tags: visual-studio-mac, visual-studio-liveshare

I'm a Windows user trying to help my cousin learn C# programming. He's got a Mac and has installed VS Mac 8.5.1. We've successfully used Live Share on VS Code, but we can't figure out how he can start Live Share on VS Mac, or if I start it, how to join a Live Share session. We can't find it on the VS Mac menus. Please help. TIA.

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac does not currently support LiveShare. I would use VS Code instead.

Comment: @MattWard does Live Share support the Mac version right now?

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac does not support Live Share currently. VS Code on macOS does support Live Share - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vscode#installation